# show toast in specific time every day

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, toast

I want to make simple android app that will show a **toast** in specific time every day say at 8:00 pm.
How do I do it? On what I should depend? alarm manager and broadcast receiver?
and in broadcast file how can i define between two events,alarm broadcast and receive new incoming sms broadcast using this outgoing call action

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {

 if (intent.getAction().equals(TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)) {
```

Comment: Why would you use `Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` ??

Comment: this is just an example to explain what i need

Comment: can u help me? how to show a toast every day in 8:00 pm?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**AlarmReceiver.java**

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // any action you want to perform will come here
        Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Retrieve a PendingIntent that will perform a broadcast */
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        setAlarm();

    }

    private void setAlarm() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval = 1000 * 60 * 20;

        /* Set the alarm to start at 8.00 PM */
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

        /* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            1000 * 60 * 20, pendingIntent);

    }

    public void cancelAlarm() {
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

The below class is to keep the alarm even after the device reboot.

**DeviceBootReceiver.java**

```
public class DeviceBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            /* Setting the alarm here */
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

            AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            int interval = 8000;
            manager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**In manifest:**

Add permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

and receivers

```
 <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>

<receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: thanks.. but i change the time and set it after tow minutes... and it give me am running toast... this is the toast i must change to appear in 8:00 pm?

Comment: it works good but there are a different in time i set time 16:25 and toast appear in 16:26 and some second

Comment: the deference in time is about 1 min

Comment: my friend i want to ask u something.. i play a sound in 8:00pm and i want to stop playing sound in 8:05

Comment: how i can do it? in mainactivity? or i must play the sound using service class?

Comment: @user7216286 I've added  method `cancelAlarm()` in activity, so you can cancel an alarm. For your case, you can use `LocalBroadcastManager`. Send a broadcast from `onReceive()` method in `AlarmReceiver.java`, capture it in your activity, and play a sound from the activity itself. You can then use a `CountDownTimer` to stop the sound in 5 minutes

Comment: my friend... everything good but there is a mistake in your code.. because i set the time calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
 it work in 18:10 but the app show me the toast again after one hour in 19:10... why? and it show me the toast again after tow minutes of the specific time 18:10